# How to convert a c string to an integer using std::stoi in C++

Tags: c++, linux, g++, c-strings

Let's say I have a sample of C-strings as follows:

```
"-fib 12"
"-fib 12"
"-e 2"
"-pi 4"
```

I would like to use the std::stoi function to get the last number in the C-strings into an integer variable. I have never before used the stoi function and it is rather confusing trying to get this to work. Thanks!

Comment: The stoi function parses the entire input string as a number of a given base. It looks like you want to "get the last number in the c-string" as base 10 into an integer right? In which case your question should be "How to convert part of a c string to an integer". I would use stringstream to do this rather than bother with stoi

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to first get past the non-numeric data before the space character to be able to use `std::stoi`.

```
char* s = "-fib 12";

// Skip until you get to the space character.
char* cp = s;
while ( *cp != ' ' && *cp != '\0') cp++;

// Defensive programming. Make sure your string is not
// malformed. Then, call std::stoi.
if ( *cp == ' ' )
{
   int num = std::stoi(cp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using std::string, you can also do something like...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str1 = "15";
    std::string str2 = "3.14159";
    std::string str3 = "714 and words after";
    std::string str4 = "anything before shall not work, 2";
    int myint1 = std::stoi(str1);
    int myint2 = std::stoi(str2);
    int myint3 = std::stoi(str3);

    // int myint4 = std::stoi(str4); // uncomment to see error: 'std::invalid_argument'
    std::cout << myint1 << '\n'
              << myint2 << '\n'
              << myint3 << '\n';
    //  << myint4 << '\n';
}
```

### output

```
15
 3 //discarded the decimal portion since it is int
714 // discarded characters after the digit
```